# How to reject incoming mails with maildrop

Tags: email

there my provider gives me the ability to filter my mails serverside via maildrop. I want to reject emails if they are from a special sender or go to a special address. I looked into the docs but couldn't find a command overview or a way how to reject mails via maildrop. Is this possible or is maildrop just to late in the chain?

Felix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be possible to reject these mails, as maildrop acts only as local delivery agent. When maildrop is executed, the mail has already been accepted by your MTA. What you can do however is filter mail for example to your spam directory. maildrop works via mailfilter scripts. You should also check the documentation for maildropfilter:

http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/maildropfilter.html

A rule for filtering mail from some sender would look about like this:

```
if (/^From: .*someone@somewhere.tld/ )
{
     to "Maildir/.Spam"
}
```

Comment: I have some addresses where ONLY spam arrives so I don't want to store them at all.

Comment: If you want to completely reject mail from certain senders, you would have to block them on the MTA level. For postfix e.g. like described here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-blacklist-reject-sender-email-address/